# What is the best way to use async / await inside Nuxt plugin?

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuex, es6-promise, nuxtjs

I wanted to do api calls inside nuxt plugin using vuex action. But when i am using await keyword Nuxt is giving me an error saying `Parsing error: Unexpected reserved word 'await'.` So, how can i use promise inside my Nuxt Plugin? Here's my associated code ->

```
export default (context) => async({ store, route, redirect }) => {
  const address = store.state.location.selectedAddress
  const payload = {}

  if (!address) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        payload.latitude = position.coords.latitude
        payload.longitude = position.coords.longitude
        const result = await store.dispatch('location/fetchLocation', payload)
        console.log(result)
        console.log(
          store.state.location.details && store.state.location.details.address
        )
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: @Bravo const result = await store.dispatch('location/fetchLocation', payload). Got the answer. Yes, "promisifying" getCurrentPosition solved the issue.

Comment: Yes, converted it. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it was returning promise. That's why used await keyword.

Comment: Oh, sorry ... I totally misread the whole question :p

Comment: It's ok. Thanks, Your comment helped to get solution.

Answer (score 1):

Converting function inside navigator.geolocation to promise solved the issue

```
export default ({ store, route, redirect }) => {
  const address = store.state.location.selectedAddress
  const payload = {}

  if (!address) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      async (position) => {
        payload.latitude = position.coords.latitude
        payload.longitude = position.coords.longitude
        const result = await store.dispatch('location/fetchLocation', payload)
        console.log(result)
        console.log(
          store.state.location.details && store.state.location.details.address
        )
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error.message)
      }
    )
  }
}
```